# ActiveMessaging generator problem - doesn't support Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemessaging

I have a problem with Activemessaging plugin and rails3 app.

my gemfile is

```
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'activemessaging', :git=>'git://github.com/spraints/activemessaging.git'
gem 'stomp'
gem 'daemons'
```

After that activemessaging folder appeared in vendor

After bundle install I want to create processor with generator

```
 rails generate processor Test
```

And I see this output:

```
ActiveMessaging: adapter reliable_msg not loaded: no such file to load -- reliable-msg
ActiveMessaging: adapter wmq not loaded: no such file to load -- wmq/wmq
ActiveMessaging: adapter beanstalk not loaded: no such file to load -- beanstalk-client
ActiveMessaging: no '/home/ruby/myapp/script/config/messaging.rb' file to load
ActiveMessaging: Loading script/app/processors/application.rb
Rails available: Adding dispatcher prepare callback.
ActiveMessaging: no '/home/ruby/myapp/script/config/messaging.rb' file to load
Could not find generator processor.
```

What did I miss ? What should I do step by step to make it works. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What guide or blog article are you using for installation?

> http://code.google.com/p/activemessaging/wiki/Installation

Their wiki doesn't resemble the steps you're taking to install, since they recommend using it as a plugin.

EDIT:

After looking at their active issues on Google Code, this project doesn't support Rails 3 yet. At least, major features are missing such as all the generators being in the wrong place such that `rails generate` won't know about them.

If you want to go it on your own, you'll have to do a bunch of manual config:

> http://code.google.com/p/activemessaging/wiki/Configuration

Comment: I'm using plugin like in this article but, rails fail with next message
ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)

Comment: Reading into the Google Code page, it quickly becomes evident that it doesn't support Rails 3 yet. Sorry, you'll have to find another approach or consider using Rails 2.3.11 instead.

Comment: Since this answer, version 0.12.0 has been released with state support for Rails 3.  (Unfortunately, I can't get it to work and it doesn't seem active at the moment, which is a pitty).

Answer (score 2):

use https://github.com/kookster/activemessaging repo in your gemfile

```
gem 'activemessaging', :git => 'git@github.com:kookster/activemessaging.git'
```

Then you can use the rails 3 generators of this gem:

```
rails g active_messaging:install 
rails g active_messaging:processor YOUR_PROCESSOR
```

This will create the config/broker.yml (broker config) and config/messaging.rb (queue config).
Its a very nice gem.

NOTE: Be sure to include the celluloid gem and daemons. In my gemfile:

```
gem 'stomp'
gem 'celluloid'
gem 'daemons'
```

Happy coding! .)